# Deploying Shield Platform Encryption using Metadata API

Tags: shield-encryption, shield

I'm planning to deploy the encrypted field from our dev org to production?
Both environment has shield platform encryption enabled. The api version of the source organization is 44 and the target is 45.

This are the steps that I'm planning to do,

```
1.) Retrieve Dev Org Metadata
2.) Go to Objects folder, Choose the object that you have encrypted fields.
3.) E.G. Contact Metadata



<fields>
    <fullName>testField</fullName>
    <encryptionScheme>CaseInsensitiveDeterministicEncryption</encryptionScheme>
    <externalId>false</externalId>
    <label>Source Home Phone</label>
    <length>72</length>
    <required>false</required>
    <trackFeedHistory>false</trackFeedHistory>
    <trackHistory>false</trackHistory>
    <type>Text</type>
    <unique>false</unique>
</fields>

4.) Update prod metadata with dev org metadata
5.) Push chages
```

Now the question is, are there any steps that I'm missing? Like manual steps etc, Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If both the orgs have encryption enabled then you don't need to perform any manual step as the encryption attribute will persist in target organisation.

The only thing to make sure is target organisation has encryption enabled which is already done so you should be good.

Here is some detail from [Salesforce documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.securityImplGuide.meta/securityImplGuide/security_pe_deployment.htm):-
[image]